# How to programmatically make a user to assign permissions on template?

Tags: django, django-models

As you all know django admin has a function to give "Permissions" for user on their admin panel ! How to do that programmatically ? For example lets say i have a super user and the user can create staff users under them as multiple roles.

And how to allow him to assign or add roles when the super user creates a profile on custom build admin panel ( am not asking for djago admin, am asking for custom own built admin panels)

[image]

Comment: Are you using Django ModelForms?

Comment: see if this helps https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-proxy-models

Comment: Check the update image on question, i need those function on my custom made admin panels for users ! @IainShelvington